# Using webpack to build a library importable with script tag

Tags: webpack

I have a Webpack project where I am building a couple of libraries. Both of them are meant to be imported with `<script>` tags. My config looks like the following:

```
entry: {
  bundle: ['./src/index', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true'],
  mylib: ['./src/loader', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true']
},
target: web,
output: {
  path: `${__dirname}/dist`, 
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  filename: '[name].js',
  library: ['mylib', '[name]'],
  libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

For my tests, my entry point is very simple:

```
module.exports = 'abracadabra';
```

According to the guide I follow [how to build a complex library with webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library), and if I understood right, this should be sufficient to get this behavior in the browser (after opening the index html file with the script tag):

```
console.log(mylib) -> 'abracadabra'
```

However, this doesn't work, and in the browser's console I can see `mylib`is defined but it has a strange shape:

```
Object {mylib: Object}
   mylib: Object
     subscribe: function subscribe(handler)
     useCustomOverlay: function useCustomOverlay(customOverlay)
     __proto__: Object__proto__:
```

Some of that code has to do with the HMR (Hot Module Replacement), but still I don't understand how I am supposed to use my module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your entrypoint?

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

Comment: I read http://andrewhfarmer.com/webpack-hmr-tutorial/ and now I understand I need to include those lines to enable HMR. However, they don't solve the problem. Right now I am attaching my exports to the window in order to continue with development:

    window.mylib = module.exports;

I will upload a sample project to Github to explore this issue and ask for advise as soon as I can…

Comment: I made some quick tests and, in my setup, Webpack seems to reload my modules *even if I don't* add the above lines… strange?

Comment: Given module.hot is true, then module.exports will contain the exported things in the entry point. Not sure where to go from here.